# Cookies created by a webview aren't being deleted with a HttpRequest

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app where I share cookies between the Webview and HttpClient by grabbing them after a login.  On iOS this works fine, on Android I have the following issue:

If the cookie is created as the result of a HTTPClinet Api call, then deleted (expired) using either a WebView or HttpClient the cookie is no longer in the cookie list.  When using HttpClient the HttpClientHandler.CookieContainer has a count of 0.

If the cookie is created using a WebView and deleted using another WebView the cookie is no longer in the cookie list.

If the cookie is created using a WebView and deleted using a HTTPClient Api call the expiration does not happen and the cookie is still in the HttpClinet's HttpClinetHandler's CookieContainer, I can see that the count is not 0.

If I look at the HttpResponse I see the expired cookie in the header:

```
"MyTestCookie=; expires=Wed, 28-Feb-2018 21:25:08 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"
```

If I look further into the CookieContainer the m_domainTable has 2 entries, one for my ip with no cookies, and one for my ip preceded with a "." that contains the cookie that should be expired/deleted but it is not expired and has the original value.

The server code that creates the cookie for both the Api call and MVC Page is:

```
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Values["token"] = "309d530f956ac04";
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and the code that Deletes / Expires it is:

```
    if (Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"] != null)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?